# Showing sections/subsections in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I want to show sections/subsections/subsubsections in Beamer, as it is in Latex (i.e. in the middle of the slide, not in sidebar)

Comment: Maybe `\frametitle{}` is a better option to you.

Comment: no, in my case, \frametitle prints on the top of the slide, not like usual text. Moreover, we lose the numbering. I will need to do it manually

Comment: So you'll need to edit the theme to insert the sections on the frame body instead of the bars. It is not easy but it is possible. I don't know how to do it for a while.

Comment: thanks, but maybe it is not worth the effort. I prefer to wait until someone else does it :) better to do this manually

Comment: What you want is easy to achieve, but your description is not enough. Where exactly do you want the sections/subsections to appear? Do you want to show them in the headline? Do you want, before each section or subsection a dedicated frame containing the section or subsection title? What theme are you currently using?

Comment: Some of the predefined themes already show this information in the headline. Have you considered switching to one of those themes?

Comment: Just to be sure: You don't mean a table of contents but as a header/footer of the actual subsection?

Comment: Or do you just want to show a table of contents? `\begin{frame} \tableofcontents \end{frame}`

Answer (score 2):

Beamer provides commands `\insertsection`, `\insertsubsection`, `\insertsubsubsection` that will insert the current section, etc.

Please see the Beamer Class User Guide, page 64 and 65. (It was v3.33 in my system).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is that you are looking for, but you can insert   `\thesection. \insertsection` or `\thesubsection. \insertsubsection` in the body frame as you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw} 

\def\SecT#1{\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{block}{}
\centering\huge\thesection. \insertsection
\end{block}
\vfill\Large #1
\end{frame}}

\begin{document}

\section{Overview}\SecT{}
\begin{frame}{Normal frame} Lore ipsum ...  \end{frame}
\section{Remarks}
\SecT{Some interesting to the audience...}
\begin{frame}{Normal frame} Lore ipsum ...  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```